# Change view of delete button

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I want to change view of delete button when user swipes on cell. How can I do this? I need to set article as read with swipe.

Answer (score 1):

try changing the subview  (cell subviews) content according to your requirement,whenever you swipe on it rather than the usual functionality, as you cannot change the delete button.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use a custom button for it. Go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076785/uibutton-in-uitableview-cell-like-delete-event) post to know how to do it.

Comment: No, this link didn't help. I just need replace an original delete button with custom button.

Comment: You can in no way change the view of the 'Delete' button. The only way you have, is to place your custom button instead of the delete button. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858697/changing-the-delete-accessory-view-in-a-uitableviewcell . This link would show you that modifying delete button is not possible(except for changing the title) and how to go about putting a custom button there. Read the most voted answer.

Comment: Yes, i tried this method, everything is fine, but i cant click the button. It's apeared but not clickable. UITableView just freezes and only delete button clickable. I add my custom button under delete button and then hide delete button.