# Change default delete button UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is there any way I can change the default delete button in a `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: You can set the `accessoryView` of the property of your cell to a `UIButton` with a custom image of your choice, and trigger deletion from the button's event handler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858697/changing-the-delete-accessory-view-in-a-uitableviewcell

Answer (score -2):

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return @"Custom Title";
}
```

Comment: No no.. Not that.. When tableview is in editmode, you can swipe in each cell/row to delete it. I wanted to change that default delete button to my custom delete button.